# Using Prometheus as Infrastructure log storage

Tags: prometheus, grafana-loki

I am using Azure Monitor to monitor my azure resources along with Log analytics workspace to store my infra logs.
I want to make a comparative study of Azure Monitor with the Prometheus and Grafana.
Can Prometheus be used to store the infra logs and if yes how is it possible and how can be retrieve the logs. We have easy interface available form Log analytics workspace to filter our required logs, does prometheus has the same.
Thanks

Comment: https://prometheus.io/docs/introduction/faq/#how-to-feed-logs-into-prometheus

Answer (score 2):

Prometheus is a tools that acts as a TSDB (Time series database) that stores only time series of **numbers**.

If you want to store string (such as your log) in Prometheus, then you'll have to do it with label. However this is a really bad idea as it will considerably increase your cardinality.

More info :

- [GH issue on supporting string type metrics](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/2227)
- [Datamodel for prometheus sample](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/data_model/#samples)
- [When does prometheus fit](https://prometheus.io/docs/introduction/overview/#when-does-it-fit)

Answer (score 1):

I think the best strategy is to use a log aggregation tool for this. If you like "Prometheus" then you must try "Loki":

> Loki is a horizontally scalable, highly available, multi-tenant log
> aggregation system inspired by Prometheus. It is designed to be very
> cost-effective and easy to operate. It does not index the contents of
> the logs, but rather a set of labels for each log stream.
>
> Loki: like Prometheus, but for logs.

See more information [here](https://grafana.com/oss/loki/).